# Unity Game will not build with GoogleMobileAds

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

I have been trying to build my game to iOS for quite some time now but whenever I try to build the project with GoogleMobileAds it won't work. The ads work fine on android but not on iOS. If i remove the GoogleMobileAds completely the project builds fine but not with the ads.

I have followed the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/unity/start) to the best of my ability but I just can't seem to get it to work. In the documentation it says that after building the Xcode project in Unity you should also get a Cocoapods workspace file but it doesn't seem to show up. What could I be doing wrong?

Thank you for any help you might give.

Comment: You need to install cocoa pods via command line at the root of your project

Comment: Then you need to ensure pod associated files exist in root. Do pod install. It'll create the necessary workspace with the google mobile ads dependency in It.

Comment: Cocoa pods can be installed with brew or ruby. This needs to be done prior to building with unity. If unity doesn't do the cocoa pods portion you can always manually add pod files and plug in dependency and run pod install.

Comment: I have already installed cocoapods using "sudo gem install cocoapods", does it make a difference if you install it like that and "install cocoa pods via command line at the root of your project"? @ApolloSoftware

Comment: I can't recognize any pod files but I am a complete iOS/Mac/XCode noob so I have no idea what would count as a pod associated files. But in the google mobile ads documentation it says that unity should generate the cocoapods workspace file, I shouldn't have to generate it myself. At least thats how I understood it. @ApolloSoftware

Comment: I tried to do a pod install in the root of the project but it just said that no 'Podfile' could be found. I would guess that the error is at the unity side but I don't know what I need to do to solve it.

Comment: Yeah. Unity is not generating your pod file for you. If you knew what dependency libraries you need you can create your own pod file but unity is supposed to do that for you.

Comment: I did a google play integration a few months back and it included google play libraries, google+ and then some auth handler. It was altogether 3-5 dependencies. The unity build script created the pod for me though. Check your unity integration and do it step by step. Also try with a blank project, that's what I did and used the pod file generated from that.

Comment: You could have another third party lib that's conflicting with ad during xcode project build process.

Comment: I ended up adding the GoogleMobileAdsSDK framework file manually and that will do for now. I had tried this once before but I couldn't get it to work then and I have no idea what I really did differently this time but whatever, I got it to work. Thank you very much for the help. @ApolloSoftware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any one happens to stumble upon this later and have the same problem. Here is how i solved it:

Unity would not generate a podfile for me like it says it should in the developer guide, maybe I haven't installed Cocoapods correctly. Regardless, in the  end, the fix was quite easy.

- I manually downloaded the Google Mobile Ads SDK and added it to the Frameworks folder in the Xcode project. (If you are more experienced with xcode/cocoapods than I am you could probably just write your own podfile that would do this for you)
- Then I changed "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)" to Yes in the Build Settings
- Lastly I added "$(inherited)" to "Other Linker Flags"

After this everything compiled like it should and the ads worked fine.